# Reality check on method of getting results from an instrument with high hysteresis?

Tags: mass, measurements, error-analysis, data-analysis

Given an instrument that has either a genuine hysteresis, or possibly just internal friction, would the following method work to get better precision.  (I don't really care about accuracy.  I want to get the same wrong answer each time....)

For the sake of simplicity, we will consider a scale with a readout to 0.1 kg

- Weigh the object  50.0 kg
- Weigh object+.1 kg weight  50.0 kg
- Weigh object+.2 kg weight  50.0 kg
- Weigh object+.3 kg weight  50.0 kg
- Weigh object+.4 kg weight  50.0 kg
- Weigh object+.5 kg weight  50.0 kg
- Weigh object+.6 kg weight  50.5 kg
- Weigh object+.7 kg weight  50.5 kg

Now reverse the sequence.

- Weigh object+.6 kg weight  50.5 kg
- Weigh object+.5 kg weight  50.5 kg
- Weigh object+.4 kg weight  50.5 kg
- Weigh object+.3 kg weight  50.5 kg
- Weigh object+.2 kg weight  50.2 kg
- Weigh object+.1 kg weight  50.2 kg

So going up, the reading change with an addition of 0.6 kg and it changed to 50.5

Coming down it changed with and addition of .2 kg, and changed to 50.2

With this scale then, I would propose that a more precise measure would be

$$(50.5 + 50.2) - (.6 +.2) \over 2$$

That is the average of the measures that finally got a difference going up, vs going down, minus the average of the weight added to get those results.

Is this a reasonable approach?

Answer (score 1):

Measuring in forward and then reverse order is a good idea. Another good idea is to use a random ordering. For more sophistication, employ a model which includes parameters indicating the size and type of hysteresis, and make the hysteresis itself the focus of study until you have got a good model of it. Once you have got that then you can adjust for the hysteresis with confidence and thus get good precision even from an instrument with a lot of hysteresis.

Comment: The forward and back came from a bathroom scale that seems internally to implement the algorithm: "If measurement - last reported is less than X, return last reported". giving the illusion of consistency

Answer (score 0):

assuming all of the other conditions are controlled I would still have doubt of seeing confirmed data on a uniform basis wouldn't state any results as fact= unanswerable